# How can I keep all my static content under content?

Tags: hugo

I have images, PDFs, etc. that I would like to store in one location (/content/) instead of /static/ folder for organizational reasons. Obviously, Hugo should copy this to static when I serve the webpage.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the `hug` tag appropriate here? :)

Answer (score 1):

Hugo can't copy things in the `content/` directory to `static/` by itself - you would have to use a pre-processor or post-processor like [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/).